# Replace s.str.startwith parameters only in a series

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a `df` on which I want to filter a column and replace the `str.startswith` parameter. Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'fname':['Anky','Anky','Tom','Harry','Harry','Harry'],'lname':['sur1','sur1','sur2','sur3','sur3','sur3'],'role':['','abc','def','ghi','','ijk'],'mobile':['08511663451212','','0851166346','','0851166347',''],'Pmobile':['085116634512','1234567890','8885116634','','+353051166347','0987654321'],'Isactive':['Active','','','','Active','']})
```

by executing the below line :

```
df['Pmobile'][df['Pmobile'].str.startswith(('08','8','+353'),na=False)]
```

I get :

```
0      085116634512
2      8885116634
4      +353051166347
```

How do i replace only the parameters I passed under `s.str.startswith()` here for example : `('08','8','+3538')` and don't touch any other number except the starting numbers inside the tuple (on the fly)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this most convenient and concise

```
df.Pmobile = df.Pmobile.replace(r'^[08|88|+3538]', '')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas's replace with regex.

below is sample code.

```
df.Pmobile.replace(regex={r'^08':'',r'^8':'',r'^[+]353':''})
```

> https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html